# The submit button should only be clickable when both checkboxes have been activated

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, vuelidate

I'm using bootstrap-vue and vuelidate. The submit button should only be clickable when both checkboxes have been activated. Unfortunately I can't get it with the checkboxes from bootstrap.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-sun-246kv

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for suggestions how to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue that you made a mistake writing the names of your fields, in the validation they are camelCase `joinLegal1` but the model is underscore, if you make it one way or the other will work.

Basically change to this:

```
validations: {
    form5: {
      join_legal1: { sameAs: sameAs(() => true) },
      join_legal2: { sameAs: sameAs(() => true) }
    }
  },
```